# Reference active table in split form without using actual table name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing an Access database. I have a number of forms that are identical. These are used to edit look up lists for different fields in my main contacts table.

e.g. there is a company field and a country field. The forms that open for each editable list are identical with repeat vba code in each becasue I cannot work out how to reference the active table from the active form.

The code I currently have for clearing all the yes/no boxes in the table is:

```
Private Sub cmdClearTicks_Click()

    Dim db As Database
   ' Dim sel  As Control

    Set db = CurrentDb
    ' Clear all ticks of selected records
    db.Execute "UPDATE ContactCompany " _
        & "SET Selected = null "


    ' Update Selected Field
   Me.Requery

End Sub
```

`ContactCompany` is the name of the table. I would like to be able to set this sub globally but cannot work out what I should replace `ContactCompany` with to reference the table in the currently open form. I've already tried `Me.RecordSource` which does not work.

I'm very grateful for what I assume is a very easy fix!

Sean posted a great fix below.  I'm now stumped with including a filter too and defining it globaly.

```
Sub SelectFiltered(RS As String)

Dim strFilter As String
Dim strSQl As String

If InStr(RS, "FROM") Then
    RS = Mid(RS, InStr(RS, "FROM") + 5)
    If InStr(RS, " ") Then RS = Left(RS, InStr(RS, " ") - 1)
End If

strFilter = Me.Filter

If Me.FilterOn = False Then

'Select Case MsgBox("No search or filter applied.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Warning")
'End Select

strSQl = "UPDATE " & RS & " " & _
"SET Selected = 1 "

Else

strSQl = "UPDATE " & RS & " " & _
"SET Selected = 1 " & _
"WHERE " & strFilter

End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQl
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Me.filter doesn't work in the global sub.  Sean - I'm sure you'll have an answer for this in a sec.  Thanks again!

Comment: are you opening these editing forms from another form where a user has the option of which list to edit? In other words, does the user click on a button a form that then opens this form?

Comment: Yes.  The user right clicks on the form field and has the option to "edit list items" from the shortcut menu.  Each field opens a different form.  Is there a way to get the form to see where it was opened from and then choose it's record source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close with using `Me.Recordsource`

`db.Execute "UPDATE " & Me.Recordsource & " SET Selected = null "`
or, if you want it as a global function, pass `Me.Recordsource` to it

```
Sub ClearTicks(RS as string,StrFilter as string)

    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    If InStr(RS, "FROM") Then 
        RS = Mid(RS, InStr(RS, "FROM") + 5)
        If InStr(RS, " ") Then RS = Left(RS, InStr(RS, " ") - 1)
    End If

    ' Clear all ticks of selected records
    db.Execute "UPDATE " & RS & " SET Selected = null "

    If StrFilter="" then 'no filter
    Else 'filter
    End If
End Sub
```

and your calling function would be:

```
Private Sub cmdClearTicks_Click()
    ClearTicks Me.Recordsource,Me.Filter
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

If you want a more reusable function method that could be expanded more easily, then call the sub/function with `Me.Name` as the parameter (e.g. `MySub Me.Name`) and then in your reusable function:

```
sub MySub(FrmName as string)
Forms(FrmName).Filter
Forms(FrmName).Recordsource
Forms(FrmName).AnyOtherParamater
```

Comment: What happens when Recordsource is an sql statement?

Comment: then some string manipulation to extract the tablename from after the FROM in the SQL

Comment: Sean, thats fantastic. Works perfectly. I thought having that I would then be able to work out the following (please see adition to original post). However I am not sure how to define a filter globaslly within the original code.

Comment: I didn't update the whole code, but I have updated the way the subroutine is called to show how to pass the extra info